# How to add startup applications in lubuntu on a specific desktop?

Tags: lxde, autostart

i want startup a programm in a specific desktop with a .desktop config file

for example firefox on desktop 2

Comment: i have posted an answer, it should work

Answer (score 2):

For tasks like this I always suggest devilspie2:

http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/

> is a window matching utility, allowing the user to perform scripted
>   actions on windows as they are created. For example you can script a
>   terminal program to always be positioned at a specific screen
>   position, or position a window on a specific workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Add `.desktop` files to `/home/username/.config/autostart` and make sure they're marked as executables.

Here is a default syntax for a .desktop file with some of the most important entries.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name="NAME OF THE APPLICATION"
Comment="WHAT DOES THE APP DO?"
Exec="EXECUTABLE PATH OF APPLICATION"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

For example :

**To Autostart firefox, execute the following commands in terminal :**

```
gedit ~/.config/autostart/firefox.desktop
```

and copy the following content in the file (firefox.desktop) and then save it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox
Comment=Firefox Web Browser
Exec=firefox
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

then mark it as executable by executing following command in terminal :

```
chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/firefox.desktop
```

Similarly you can autostart other applications.
For applications that have their binaries in /usr/bin , full path isn't required (like firefox)

Logout and login again to see the changes!

[For more info click here](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=111&f=8)

Comment: I don't understand from this answer how to start in specific desktop. Not just to make startup file. Also this is copy from here http://askubuntu.com/questions/376187/kubuntu-autostart-program-in-a-specific-desktop where the answer is again not for the question